# How to include a function in a template with template tag

Tags: php, functions, templates

This feels like a silly question, but I'm not thinking straight and can't seem to find any clear documentation for what I'm trying to do.

I have the function below that adds a Google Map section in the Customizer where you can input address, etc. I would like to display the map in my theme with a template tag. I can add it to the homepage similar to other sections I have with a hook like `add_action( 'homepage', '', '');`. However, I want to insert this one in the footer area or possible other areas.

I've tried things such as `<?php map_section(); ?>` and `<?php display_map_section(); ?>` with no success. Am I missing something?

```
<?php
/**
 * Map Section
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

// Returns the main instance of Map_Section to prevent the need to use globals.
function Map_Section() {
    return Map_Section::instance();
} // End Map_Section()

Map_Section();

// Main Map_Section Class
final class Map_Section {
    // Map_Section The single instance of Map_Section.
    private static $_instance = null;
    // Constructor function.
    public function __construct() {
        $this->plugin_url       = get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/map-section/'; 
        $this->plugin_path      = get_template_directory() . '/inc/map-section/';

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'map_section_setup' ) );
    }

    // Main Map_Section Instance
    // Ensures only one instance of Map_Section is loaded or can be loaded.
    public static function instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) )
            self::$_instance = new self();
        return self::$_instance;
    } // End instance()

    // Cloning is forbidden.
    public function __clone() {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Cheatin&#8217; huh?' ), '1.0.0' );
    }

    // Unserializing instances of this class is forbidden.
    public function __wakeup() {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Cheatin&#8217; huh?' ), '1.0.0' );
    }

    // Setup all the things.
    public function map_section_setup() {
        add_action( 'customize_preview_init', array( $this, 'map_section_customize_live_preview' ), 999 );
        add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'map_section_customize_register' ) );
    }

    // Customizer controls and settings.
    public function map_section_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

        // Map
        $wp_customize->add_section( 'map' , array(
            'title'             => __( 'Map', 'map-section' ),
            'description'       => __( 'To change the location of the marker on the map, edit the information below, click <Strong>Save & Publish</strong> and refresh the page to see the new location.', 'map-section' ),
            'panel'             => 'homepage',
            'priority'          => 13
        ) );

            // Title
            $wp_customize->add_setting( 'map_title', array(
                'default'           => __( 'The White House', 'map-section' ), 
                'transport'         => 'postMessage'
            ) );    
            $wp_customize->add_control( 'map_title', array(
                'label'             => __( 'Map Title', 'map-section' ),
                'type'              => 'text',
                'section'           => 'map',
            ) );

            ...

            // Zoom Level
            $wp_customize->add_setting( 'map_zoom_level' , array(
                'default'           => '14',
                'transport'         => 'postMessage'
            ) );
            $wp_customize->add_control( 'map_zoom_level', array(
                'label'             => __( 'Zoom Level', 'map-section' ),
                'type'              => 'range',
                'input_attrs'       => array(
                    'min'           => 1,
                    'max'           => 20,
                    'step'          => 1
                ),
                'section'           => 'map',
            ) );

    }

    // Enqueue Customizer live preview.
    public function map_section_customize_live_preview(){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'map-section-customize-live-preview', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/map-section/js/customizer.js', array(  'jquery', 'customize-preview' ), '', true );
    }

    // Map section
    public static function display_map_section() {
    ?>

        <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'display_map' , '1' ) == '1' ) { ?>
            <section id="map" class="wrapper">
                <div class="map-overlay" onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'"></div><iframe width="100%" height="400" src="http://www.mapi.ie/create-google-map/map.php?width=100%&amp;height=400&amp;hl=en&amp;q=<?php echo rawurlencode( get_theme_mod( 'map_address' , __( '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW', 'map-section' ) )); ?>%2C%20<?php echo rawurlencode( get_theme_mod( 'map_city_town' , __( 'Washington', 'map-section' ) )); ?>%20<?php echo rawurlencode( get_theme_mod( 'map_state_province' , __( 'DC', 'map-section' ) )); ?>%2C%20<?php echo rawurlencode( get_theme_mod( 'map_country' , __( 'USA', 'map-section' ) )); ?>%20<?php echo rawurlencode( get_theme_mod( 'map_zip_postal_code' , __( '20500', 'map-section' ) )); ?>+(<?php echo rawurlencode( get_theme_mod( 'map_title' , __( 'The White House', 'map-section' ) )); ?>)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=<?php echo rawurlencode( get_theme_mod( 'map_zoom_level' , __( '14', 'map-section' ) )); ?>&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>  
            </section>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php
    }
} // End Class
```

Comment: Your function is a static method in a class `Map_Section::display_map_section()`

Comment: @milo it didn't work at first because I had a typo but now it does. If you can add this as an answer, I'll accept it as correct.